# expectioncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I have to read a file into an object. The Object has HashMap<<MyObj>,String> inside.

Im using jackson object mapper.As Im trying to read it from the file I get: **expectioncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type**

because but  MyObjKeyDeserializer **is not beeing called** at all.

MyObj class:

```
public class MyObj implements Serializable, Comparable<MyObj> {//fileds..}
```

I registered this module to the ObjectMapper:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(MyObj.class, new MyObjSerializer());
module.addKeyDeserializer(MyObj.class, new MyObjKeyDeserializer());
```

```
public class MyObjKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {
    public static final String SEPARATOR = ":";

    @Override
    public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String[] parts = key.split(SEPARATOR, 2);
        return new MyObj(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }
}
```

What am I missing and why the MyObjKeyDeserializaor is not beeing called?